# Ubuntu becomes slow after huge file move during Deep learning

Tags: ubuntu, slowdown

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. While I'm moving huge dataset (over 200GB) from SSD to HDD, my PC becomes slow after around 1 hours later. At the same time I'm executing Deep learning program(it becomes stop after same hour).

I checked CPU, RAM and IO but there are no problems.

Some command works fast(ex ls) but others are not(ex apt). And also the reboot speed becomes extremely slow.

Comment: Try to disable SWAP (`sudo swapoff -a`). What you describe could be easily attributed to the kernel evicting running programs from RAM and then you feel like everything becomes slow because when you finally decide to reboot/power off, the kernel needs to actually terminate all the applications whose code now resides on the disk and has to be read back which naturally takes time. In a perfect world the kernel shouldn't do that but it still does.

Comment: If that's caused by SWAP yet you cannot disable it, try to tune it this way: `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10` or even all the way down to 1.

Comment: I cannot do what I did again, but the above inferences make sense. Thank you guys.